# Use nginx in front of the haproxy for socket.io app

Tags: nginx, websocket, proxy, haproxy

Following is my app proxy flow:

**nginx(host-a:80) -> haproxy(host-b:5000) -> socket.io app (host-c:3000)**

I can access the app via haproxy(host-b:5000), it works fine, the http can upgrade to socket connect.

however, it's fail when I access via nginx(host-a:80).

- When I config the nginx as below, http can upgrade to socket connection, but got 503 error, it seems the request cannot fall into the socket.io app properly.

```
    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass         http://node_server_pool;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

- When I config the nginx as below, I can fetch the data from the app, but the connection cannot upgrade to websocket and the socket.io down grade to polling mode.

```
    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass         http://node_server_pool;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Is it possible to run nginx in front of a socket proxy server like this ?

Comment: Which component actually generates the 503 error?  Does HAProxy log the request? If so, what error code does it show and what does the logged [session state at disconnection](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8.5) tell you?  This is the value that HAProxy logs as `----` on successful requests. The first two `--` will change to a different code if HAProxy is in any way unhappy about what just happened.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for your hints very much. The 503 error happens in Haproxy. And finally, we found it's because I set a wrong server name in the haproxy and cause the request cannot find the properly app. The problem is not in the proxy config.

Comment: I'm glad you found it.  I'm voting to close this as a problem that can no longer be reproduced/simple typographical error.